# Assembly Language Primer video tutorials?

Tags: video, assembly

I've seen a lot of text based Assembly tutorials but finding it tough to learn from them. What video tutorials exist for Assembly Language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this link in Reddit Programming section yesterday, looks pretty good :

There are 10 parts to it, posting Part 1. Rest of the links are there in the below article.

http://securitytube.net/Assembly-Primer-for-Hackers-(Part-1)-System-Organization-video.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found lots of good stuff with this query:

> [**Google query:** *assembly language tutorial video*](http://www.google.com/search?q=assembly+language+tutorial+video&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Out of those, the first one looks pretty good:

> [Assembly Language Tutorial (5 videos) a series of video-tutorials by Neil Dickson](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/series?name=qdrYRTz8Z)